# Aggregate function creates unwanted vector within data frame

Tags: r, function, vector, dataframe, aggregate

I've been experiencing a strange problem with creating dataframes within a function. However, using the same method outside of a data.frame works fine!

Here is the basic function, I use it to calculate the mean, standard deviation and standard error for a data set:

```
aggregateX<- function(formula, dataset){
  output<-aggregate(formula, dataset, mean) #calculate mean
  sdev<-aggregate(formula, dataset, sd) #calculate sd
  output$sd<-sdev[length(sdev)] #place sd in same data.frame
  output$se<-output$sd/sqrt(max(as.numeric(dataset$P))) #calculate se
  names(output$sd)<-"sd";names(output$se)<-"se" #attatch correct names
  return(output)
}
```

The function works but has a strange method of combining the data.frame as an output. The first variable (mean) is formatted correctly, but both the standard deviation and standard error are structured  as a vector within the dataframes first row.

i.e. when you view the output in RStudio it looks something like this:
[image]

This wouldn't matter, but ggplot2 runs into some difficulty when trying to process this unusual data.frame. Any advice on how to form the data.frame without the strange vector would be much appreciated.

Comment: Actually, the issue is your use of `length` in `output$sd<-sdev[length(sdev)]`. The output of `aggregate` is a data.frame not a vector, so the value of your index is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
aggregateX<- function(formula, dataset){
  denom <- sqrt(max(as.numeric(dataset$P)))
  aggregate(formula, dataset, function(x){
    s <- sd(x)
    c(mean=mean(x),sd=s,se=s/denom)
  })
}
```

Assuming `dataset` has a column named `P`.

Comment: Just for clarity for others reading this: 

$P is used to as the number of subjects in the dataset.

Comment: Note that the last column of `aggregateX` is actually a vector of vectors (which have 3 elements in this case). To split them into separate columns, execute `do.call(data.frame, aggregateX)`.

Answer (score 1):

This could be:

```
aggregateX<- function(formula, dataset){
        aggregate(formula, dataset, function(x){
               c(mean=mean(x),
                   sdev = sd(x),
 #  output$sd<-sdev[length(sdev)] #place sd in same data.frame
 #  that mades no sense.
 #   the length of a data.frame is the number of columns
                   se=sd(x)/length(x)   #length of a vector makes sense
                   )                               }
        )                     }
```

Comment: Does not work. You need `c()` instead of `list()` to return more than one column, and `sdev` is not defined when evaluating `se=sdev/length(x)`. And I don't think the OP wants to divide by `length(x)`. Also it's missing a `}` in the end. :-)

Comment: I freely admit it wasn't tested in the absence of a dput or code constructed dataset. I've probably made the mistake of trying to use `list()` instead of `c()` before. Maybe the OP will tell us what is really the goal rather than leaving it to the reader to intuit the intent from incorrect code.

Answer (score 0):

Another option I found, which also works. However, I believe the solution offered by Ferdinand.kraft is simpler!

Something to do with the aggregate function nesting the vector. Adding a [,1] command to the functioned seemed to solve it. See below.

```
    aggregateX<- function(formula, dataset){
  output<-aggregate(formula, dataset, mean)
  sdev<-aggregate(formula, dataset, sd)
  output$sd<-sdev[length(sdev)][,1]
  output$se<-output$sd/sqrt(max(as.numeric(dataset$P)))
 # names(output$sd)<-"sd";names(output$se)<-"se" #fix names
  return(output)
}
```