# How to group by two columns in R

Tags: r, group-by

I have a data frame that I am trying to group and then sum based on two columns. The two columns are characters with one being month and the other variable.

The following is a sample of the data frame and structure.

```
#row.names   month    variable   amount
  1          1-Jan       x        1000
  2          1-Jan       x        3000
  3          2-Feb       z        5000
  4          2-Feb       y        3000
```

I tried to group the data first and then I was going to try to summarise, however I am unable to get group_by_() to do the trick. Below is the code I tried.

```
byVarMonth <- group_by_(df, variable, (as.date(month)))
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: (1) Use `group_by()` (2) It's `as.Date()` (3) you need a format in `as.Date()`

Comment: So then `group_by(df, variable, month = months(as.Date(month, "%d-%b"), TRUE))` should get it done but I don't really see a reason to convert that column to Date anyway.  You could just group it as-is.

Answer (score 36):

You apparently are not interested in taking your Character [month] as a Date variable. Considering that I'm not wrong you could simply do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

tab %>%
  group_by(month, variable) %>%
  summarise(a_sum=sum(amount),
            a_mean=(mean(amount)))
```

and get this:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
Groups: month

  month variable a_sum a_mean
1 1-Jan        x  4000   2000
2 2-Feb        y  3000   3000
3 2-Feb        z  5000   5000
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit old-fashioned solution but works with the built-in R function `aggregate`, no need for installing `dplyr`:

```
res <- aggregate(amount ~ variable + month, 
  data=df, 
  function(x) { 
    c(sum=sum(x), avg=mean(x)) 
})
```

The first parameter is a formula. Left of the `~` you specify the column to be aggregated, the right-hand side lists the column names to be grouped by, separated by `+`. The second parameter `data=` specifies the input data frame. Finally the third parameter is a function that takes the vector `x` (the values selected for each group) and returns either a scalar or a vector of various aggregate results (here we calculate both the sum and the mean of `amount` in each group, see e.g. [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19080280)).

If you print `res`, it will look like this:

```
variable month amount.sum amount.avg
1        x 1-Jan       4000       2000
2        y 2-Feb       3000       3000
3        z 2-Feb       5000       5000
```

However, what you *don't see* is that the last 2 columns are actually a single column of two-long vectors (run `dim(res)` to verify). To split that last column into two, do this (inspired by [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42406053)):

`res <- do.call(data.frame, res)`

Note that `aggregate` can be invoked with other parameters, please consult `?aggregate` for details.

Answer (score 2):

... or, you can use an alternative sintax:

```
summarise(group_by(df, variable), sum(amount), mean(amount))
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

[dplyr **1.1.0**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#dplyr-110) introduced the [`.by`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/dev/reference/dplyr_by.html) argument in `mutate` and `summarize` for one-time grouping operations (please note at the time of this post, this argument is in the experimental lifecycle):

```
df %>% 
  summarize(total = sum(amount),
            .by = c(month, variable))
```

`.by` accepts [tidy-select](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) helpers for more concise column selection.

---

**`.by` versus `group_by`**

The difference between using this argument and the `group_by` function is that `.by` automatically ungroups after `summarize` (or `mutate`), returning a data frame object. Unless you `ungroup` (or use the `.groups` argument in `summarize`) after using `group_by` you get grouped data frame object, which could have unintended consequences in your pipe chain. `summarize` throws a warning in this case since it is easy to miss. Just something to be aware of because most often data needs to be ungrouped.

```
df %>% 
  summarize(total = sum(amount),
            .by = c(month, variable)) %>% 
  class()
[1] "data.frame"

df %>% 
  group_by(month, variable) %>% 
  summarize(total = sum(amount)) %>% # pipe to ungroup() or use .groups arg to get a data frame
  class()

`summarise()` has grouped output by 'month'. You can override using the `.groups`
argument.
[1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```